# How do I upload a pdf file?

Tags: support

I want to upload a pdf file while answering a question, but could find no such option on both the desktop and mobile version.

Is this present and I'm missing it, or absent?

Comment: What's in this pdf that's so essential to the answer but which you can't put in the body of the post itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not support vector-type images (SVG, pdf, etc.). This means that you can't upload pdf files here. What you can do is to take a screenshot of the file - or to use any vector-to-raster converter - and upload the picture. But please bear in mind that if the content of the pdf is text and equations, you are supposed to actually type those, not to include a picture of the text. Only use pictures to include actual graphs, such as diagrams, photos, drawings, etc.

In case you don't know how to type math equations here, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference). For more information about vector-type images, see [Allow SVG image uploads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92568/allow-svg-image-uploads).